# makefile with multiple jobs -j and subdirectories

Tags: makefile

Imagine you have a make file with subdirectories to be built using "make -c". Image you have 4 target directories. 3 out of 4 are done, 1 needs to run. You run the overall makefile with:

```
make -j 4
```

Is there a way to tell the makefile system to run the remaining target with make -c -j 4 instead of just 1 ? If two targets would be missing I would like make -c -j 2 for each one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll expand on Beta's (correct) answer.  All the individual make processes communicate with each other and guarantee that there will never be more than N jobs running across all the different make invocations, when you use `-jN`.  At the same time, they always guarantee that (assuming there are at least N jobs that can possibly be run across all the make invocations), N jobs will always be running.

Suppose instead that you had 4 directories with "something to do", which somehow you could know a priori, and so instead of invoking one instance of make with `-j4` and letting that make invoke the 4 submakes normally, you force each of the submakes to be invoked with `-j1`.  Now suppose that the first directory had 10 targets out of date, the second had 5, the third had 20, and the fourth had 100 out of date targets.  At first you have 4 jobs running in parallel.  Then once the second directory's 5 targets are built, you only have 3 jobs running in parallel, then 2, then for the rest of the build of the fourth directory you'll have only one target being built at a time and no parallelism.  That's much Less Good.

The way GNU make works, instead, all four instances of make are communicating.  When the second directory is done, the jobs it was running are available to the other directories, etc.  By the end of the build the fourth directory is building four jobs at a time in parallel.  That's much More Good.

Maybe if you explained *why* you want to do this, it would be more helpful to us in constructing an answer.

Comment: The last sentence says it all. The only places where I see people having problems with parallel make are bad defined makefiles. If the makefile is well defined, make will not make errors and will run optimally; that is there is no way that, with a given N, that there is a better strategy then the one currently used by make.

Answer (score 1):

Make handles that automatically. From [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Options_002fRecursion):

> If you set [-j] to some numeric value ‘N’ and your operating system
>   supports it... the parent make and all the sub-makes will communicate
>   to ensure that there are only ‘N’ jobs running at the same time
>   between them all.

Comment: Perhaps my question wasn't clear. I know that there won't be more than -j jobs. My question is that if there is one target I want make -j 4 on that one, two targets make -j 2 on each, 4 target, make -j 1 on each...

Comment: No, you cannot do that.  First of all, how can make know which directories are up to date and which have more work to do?  It cannot know until it invokes make in the subdirectory, and by that time it's too late.  Second of all, why would this be useful?  In fact, doing what you're asking would REDUCE the total amount of parallelization you could achieve, since it might be that the first directory only had one file to build while the second one had 100 files to build: now the second directory can only build one at a time while the first directory is idle.

Comment: Reduce ? How can wanting to call make -j 2 instead of make -j 1 reduce the parallelization ?   Is there a make-like framework that can do this ?

Comment: I'm not aware of any make-like framework that can do what you appear to be asking for... but maybe I'm just not understanding what you want.

Comment: @MadScientist: I think it's much more likely that madreblu doesn't understand what you're saying.